# Cannot access to objects values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-admin

I am trying to access to my objects value `Id` but I am having troubles doing it and I do not really understand why.
My object looks like this:

[image]

The `Id` value should be easily accessible by this code:

```
console.log('My object', this.props.record.Id);
```

or perhaps by this:

```
console.log('My object', this.props.record["Id"]);
```

But neither of those works, the website displays this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined.
```

I also checked if `this.props.record` is really an object using `typeof` and it is an object.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you get if you log `Object.keys(this.props.record)` ?

Comment: @GaëlS I get following error: `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`.

Comment: Try `this.props.Id`

Comment: Here is your answer then. `this.props.record` is null and it can seem misleading but `typeof === 'object'`

Comment: Can you console log "this.props.record". I think it is undefined,that is why you are getting that error.

Comment: @VardanGupta The image is an output of that.

Comment: Try this: this.props.record && this.props.record.Id

Comment: @VardanGupta Great, that does return the ID, thank you! I still dont understand why it works like this, would you explain please?

Comment: How is the data for `this.props.record` assigned?

Comment: It is just first checking whether we have anything in record or not. If we have,then look for Id property.

Comment: simply do `console.table(this.props)` and you will see how the browser will print a table in the form of keys and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly the scenario.

Commonly, props have `initialValues` which you might have missed out there.

to confirm that, try doing this:

`console.log('My object', this.props.record && this.props.record.Id);`

To make the app run, you need first to include this `this.props.record &&` before any usage of `this.props.record.Id`, if it worked, we will work on setting a better solution to that problem by initializing a default value for `record` property.